# Do SmartPointers passed as a generic pointer type need to be freed before passing to another function?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I presume Smart Pointers need to be specifically deleted when passed as a generic pointer type that gets assigned a value or a memory or resource leak will occur?

I'll use `CComPtr` as example.  Will This Leak:

```
CComPtr<ISomeComObj> mycomobj;
SomeOtherComObject1->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
SomeOtherComObject2->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
```

If so, I presume the solution is to:

```
CComPtr<ISomeComObj> mycomobj;
SomeOtherComObject1->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
mycomobj=NULL;
SomeOtherComObject2->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
```

Or CString example:

```
void GetString(char **pstring)
{
  *pstring=new char[123];
  strncpy(*pstring, "Whatever", 122);
}

// this leaks, correct?
CString s;
GetString(&s);
GetString(&s);
    
// this is okay, correct?
CString c;
GetString(&c);
c=NULL;
GetString(&c);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ultimately depends on how the start pointer and the function are written, but in general, with ATL pointers and functions coded as they should be:

In debug mode:

```
CComPtr<ISomeComObj> mycomobj;
SomeOtherComObject1->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
SomeOtherComObject2->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj); // will throw an ATL assert
```

Extract from `atlcomcli.h`:

```
...
//The assert on operator& usually indicates a bug.  If this is really
//what is needed, however, take the address of the p member explicitly.
T** operator&() throw()
{
    ATLASSERT(p==NULL);
    return &p;
}
...
```

In release, you'll have a problem. So what you should do is this:

```
CComPtr<ISomeComObj> mycomobj;
SomeOtherComObject1->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
mycomobj.Release();
SomeOtherComObject2->FunctionToFindComObject(&mycomobj);
```

Note it's good to know `CComPtr::Release()` can be called safely (in debug and release mode) even if the contained pointer is null, so this works fine for example:

```
CComPtr<ISomeComObj> mycomobj;
mycomobj.Release();
```

PS: my advice is always use debug mode to develop.